# Avoid duplicate data processing between Kafka data centers

Tags: apache-kafka

In active - active Kafka design, when data are replicated from DC1 to DC2 (withing same or different zone). How to make sure that DC2 consumer do not process data that has already been processed by DC1 consumer? What Kafka level config should be done?

Comment: Why would you have multiple consumers running? Typically you'd only start DC2 consumer when DC1 is down

Answer (score 1):

The consumer only knows about the local offsets topic, and the cluster doesn't know its being replicated into another, so there's no config in the broker that would modify consumer behavior with respect to another cluster.

I assume you're using MirrorMaker2, which has the ability to [translate topic offsets using timestamp markers](https://blog.cloudera.com/a-look-inside-kafka-mirrormaker-2/), which a secondary failover consumer can pick up from, but this assumes it is only running after the source DC has failed, not in parallel, in which case, since it's a separate topic, different maintained consumer group, etc, you'll either need to have a cross-DC distributed lock or find a place to centrally store and manage offsets that both consumers will use